# Empty title for tag wiki edit under "Activity"->"Reviews"

Tags: bug, status-completed, recent-activity, tag-wiki, suggested-edits

In my "Reviews" tab [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/300/regdwight?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_reviews), I just stumbled upon this:

[image]

Turns out that was an [edit to the "writing" tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/edit-suggestions/42). I suppose the "Reviews" tab should be saying just that, "approved suggested edit on the [writing](/questions/tagged/writing) tag wiki" or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed, all wikis now appear in the revision list correctly